# Content Access for not showing specific Content types on Add Content page

Tags: nodes, users

I am new in Drupal. I have one simple query.

I am trying to create one Editor role for one website. Editor would be able to create, update and delete one specific content type "Documents".

I have given permission using ACCESS CONTROL and also I have checked in Permission page. It only has permission to add "Documents Content Type" but still when I login as an Editor and try to create new "Document Content", it shows all the content types. I want to hide other content types for Editor.

So basically it should show only "Document Content Type" for a user.

**P.S. This is bit different question. So don't make it as duplicate question Pls.**

Answer (score 0):

check your permission tab once again

Comment: Expand on your answer please

Comment: Yes, please specify more.

Comment: Thanks @harsh for your comment. I have checked permission page again and it helped. Needed to uncheck 1 permission.